# Refrence of this hadith related to battle of trench?

Tags: hadith, reference-request, seerah

What is the reference of the  hadith in which is mentioned that:

> The Prophet Muhammad (Peace be Upon Him) tied two stones on his belly while digging a trench during **Battle of the Trench**

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4101

Answer (score 2):

This hadith is brought by Al-Tirmidhi in his book Jami'at-Tirmidhi.

---

> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ أَبِي زِيَادٍ، حَدَّثَنَا سَيَّارُ بْنُ حَاتِمٍ، عَنْ سَهْلِ بْنِ أَسْلَمَ، عَنْ يَزِيدَ بْنِ أَبِي مَنْصُورٍ، عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ أَبِي طَلْحَةَ، قَالَ شَكَوْنَا إِلَى رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم الْجُوعَ وَرَفَعْنَا عَنْ بُطُونِنَا عَنْ حَجَرٍ حَجَرٍ فَرَفَعَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم عَنْ حَجَرَيْنِ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى هَذَا حَدِيثٌ غَرِيبٌ لاَ نَعْرِفُهُ إِلاَّ مِنْ هَذَا الْوَجْهِ ‏.‏

**Which translates to:**

> Anas bin Malik narrated from Abu Talhah who said:
> "We complained to the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) of hunger and we raised(our garments ) from our stomachs (exposing) a stone (on each of us). So the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) raised (his garment exposing) two stones."‏.‏

---

**Reference  : Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2371**

**In-book reference  : Book 36, Hadith 68**

**This is graded daif(weak) by Al-Albani**

---

Thank you: [Sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/) for answer reference [here](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2371)